# Глючит анимация html js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Я делаю всплывающее окно, над кнопкой, при успешном добавлении в корзину. 
все вроде работает, но проблема если товар находится в слайдере, slick.

Почему то там координаты как то по другому считаются и я не могу нормально нацелить окно на кнопку.

Я использую абсолютное позиционирование окна. Можете есть какое то готовое решение, подскажите буду благодарен?

Набросал [код](http://cssdeck.com/labs/xlfmlert):

```js
$('.carusel').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: true,
});

var tooltip_cart;
var cart_button_height;

function tooltip_cart_animate(txt) {
  //if (!txt) txt = "Добавлено в корзину";
  tooltip_cart.animate({
    opacity: 1,
    top: "-=" + cart_button_height
    // height: "toggle"
  }, 500, function() {
    tooltip_cart.mouseleave(function () {
      $(this).css({opacity: 0.2});
    });
  });
}

// получение координат смещения элемента относительно левого верхнего угла окна
function getOffsetSum(elem) {
  var top=0, left=0
  while(elem) {
    top = top + parseFloat(elem.offsetTop)
    left = left + parseFloat(elem.offsetLeft)
    elem = elem.offsetParent
  }

  return {top: Math.round(top), left: Math.round(left)}
}

// установка окна на кнопку
function tooltip_cart_offset(t) {
  var offset = getOffsetSum(t);
  cart_button_height = t.offsetHeight;
  console.log(offset, 'W', t.offsetWidth,  tooltip_cart.outerWidth(), 'H', t.offsetHeight, tooltip_cart.outerHeight());
  offset.left = offset.left - (tooltip_cart.outerWidth() - t.offsetWidth)/2;
  offset.top = offset.top - (tooltip_cart.outerHeight() - t.offsetHeight) - 8;
  tooltip_cart.offset(offset);
 
  
}

// функция выбора подарка и отправка его в корзину
function ajax_submit_gift(t, id) {
  tooltip_cart_offset(t);
  tooltip_cart_animate();
}

$(document).ready(function () { 
  // alert(1);
  tooltip_cart = $('.tooltip_cart');
    
  $('.my button').click(function () {
    // $('body').append('1111');
     ajax_submit_gift(this, 1);
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eee; 
  height: 100%;
 }

.wrap {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin : 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
  } 

 div.my {
  background: #ddd; 
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 210px;
  margin-bottom: 1em
}

.tooltip_cart{
  position:absolute;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:block;
  background:#fe547b;
  color:#ffffff;
  padding:12px;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  /* width: 200px; */
  font-size:1.1em;
  //height:50px;
  //line-height:25px;
  border-radius:5px;
  text-align:center;
  opacity:0.2;
  //transition:.25s ease-in-out;
 
 

}
.tooltip_cart:after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    //top:50px;
    bottom:-8px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-8px;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    border-left:8px solid transparent;
    border-right:8px solid transparent;
    border-top:8px solid #fe547b;
    //transition:.25s ease-in-out;
  }
```

```html
<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  
   <div class="my">
      <p>товар5</p>
      <button>Кнопка</button>
    </div>
  
     <div class="my">
      <p>товар5</p>
      <button>Кнопка</button>
    </div>
  
  <div class="carusel">
    <div class="my">
      <p>товар1</p>
      <button>Кнопка</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="my">
      <p>товар2</p>
      <button>Кнопка</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="my">
      <p>товар3</p>
      <button>Кнопка</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="my">
      <p>товар4</p>
      <button>Кнопка</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="my">
      <p>товар5</p>
      <button>Кнопка</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="tooltip_cart">
    <a href="#"><b>Добавлено</b><br>
     Перейти в корзину →</a>
  </div>
```

При клике на кнопку, происходит всплывание окна над кнопкой, но если нажимаем в карусели, то окошко где то справа далеко всплывает.

И, кстати, если после карусели нажимаем на обычный товар, не в карусели, то окошко сначала почему то криво всплывает, а повторное нажатие - как надо.

Comment: my наверно relative должен быть ?

Comment: где именно релатив? тут смысл в том, что на странице как раз может быть и так товары и в каруселях в нескольких, релатив относительно чего делать. но задумку я понял, я попробую добавлять окно в блок с товаром и уже относительно его сдвигать

Comment: реалтив это родитель для всплывающего окна ... относительно него ты и будешь двигать свой элемент ... как у меня в примере ...если не указывать релатив то родителем будет body что не айс ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я просто эмитировал `click` - так вроде смотрится лучше ?

> смотреть на всю страницу

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
}

.focus-elem {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .4s linear;
}

button:focus~.focus-elem {
  animation: show .5s linear;
}

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: .3;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <p>lorem4</p>
  <button>item</button>
  <div class="focus-elem">
    Добавлено
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <p>lorem4</p>
  <button>item</button>
  <div class="focus-elem">
    Добавлено
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <p>lorem4</p>
  <button>item</button>
  <div class="focus-elem">
    Добавлено
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <p>lorem4</p>
  <button>item</button>
  <div class="focus-elem">
    добавлено
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ну я смысл понял, вы имеете ввиду добавлять сразу окошко в блок? так да, работает...

Comment: ну конечно в блок , просто я в jquery чуть чуть волоку но смысл в том что надо этот всплывающий блок append в тот откуда должно всплывать - понимаешь ?

Comment: да именно так и делаю сейчас, доделаю отпишу

Comment: Да прокатило. сделал перемещение apppend окна в товарный блок и там уже всплываю